# "Logarithmic derivative of a p-adic number"

Tags: power-series, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Coleman, in "Division Values in Local Fields", (Inventiones math. 53, 91 - 116 (1979)), says that

> In his work on cyclotomic fields Kummer observed that various formal operations
>   on power series had number theoretic applications. Perhaps the most
>   striking of these was Kummer's idea of taking logarithmic derivatives of p-adic
>   numbers.

Why did Kummer want to do that?

Comment: See Section 13.7 of Washington's Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields (2nd edition). The idea is that certain $p$-adic units $u$ may be special values of a $p$-adic power series, so the logarithmic derivative of that series at the same point is the "logarithmic derivative" of $u$.  Of course there's a certain ambiguity here (what if $u$ is a special value of another $p$-adic power series at similar points?), but to see how this is handled just look in Washington's book.

Comment: @KCd Thanks (I had just found that in Washington). However, I'm not sure of the original "why" for Kummer. (I know about some modern applications, e.g. in Iwasawa theory.)

Comment: See http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~franz/publ/hil.pdf, which is the introduction to the English translation of Hilbert's Zahlbericht. Search in this document for the term "logarithmic."  You'll find a discussion of Kummer's work on higher reciprocity laws and a reference to Section 131 of the Zahlbericht.